# Freeze a gui jdbc ,when save a data,why?

Tags: java

Hy i create one project (i maked using this turtorial: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/save_a_new_record.html  using this database: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_and_databases.html)

When I want to save new record the program is freezing.(I want to when I save a new data the program will able to wrok with next and prev buttons)

The save_button i changed with these code:

```
private void btnSaveRecordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    //...................................................................................
    String first = textFirstName.getText();
    String last = textLastName.getText();
    String job = textJobTitle.getText();
    String ID = textID.getText();
    int newID = Integer.parseInt(ID);

    try {
        String insertSql = "INSERT INTO Workers (ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,JOB_TITLE) VALUES(" + newID + ",'" + first + "','" + last + "','" + job + "')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertSql);


        rs.next();
        int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
        String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
        String first2 = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String last2 = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String job2 = rs.getString("Job_Title");

        textID.setText(id);
        textFirstName.setText(first2);
        textLastName.setText(last2);
        textJobTitle.setText(job2);

    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
```

(cleared the blocking segment(false,trues..) but now I have this error:

> ResultSet not open. Operation 'next' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is OFF.

)

Comment: Where is `rs` defined?

Comment: Learn to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Just in case LAST_NAME is `O'Reilly` for example.

Comment: Can you do an err.printStackTrace() instead err.getMessage(), and post that in the question? It might help in finding the real error.

Comment: I think you are missing a query here, maybe it got lost while posting? You're doing an insert, but you seem to expect a select. In the tutorial, they are doing a 'select' with a result, hence the resultset. You're doing an insert, which doesn't have a result, hence your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The freezing is because you are doing a JDBC call in the Thread of the UI. You should never do that, but instead create a new thread and execute the work there.

When updating the UI, also don't call Swing methods directly, but use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

The error you get is because you're doing an insert, but you seem to expect a select. In the tutorial, they are doing a 'select' with a result, hence the resultset. You're doing an insert, which doesn't have a result, which explains the error when you're calling next. Just add the following, under the executeUpdate() and it will work:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Workers";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: Yours is good advice, and explains what could be a reason for a temporary freeze, but is not the cause of his permanent freeze nor his error message. In short, it does not answer the main question.

Comment: Thanks, but the question doesn't say the program is freezing permanently. My guess is that the program tries to connect to the database, times out, gives the error which might take some time, and the UI freezes while doing that. But I read: why is my app freezing, not why is my DB connection not working.